# How to populate knockout observable array on initial load of page?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an of a few thousand objects that I initially load into an observable array on the initial load of my view model in the following way:

```
self.ReadingListItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData.ReadingListItems);
```

however this makes the page really slow and the page takes a long time to load, is there any alternative way that is faster than this?

Comment: Do you need to use `ko.mapping`?  i.e. do you need to have view models created for each reading list item?  And do you need to load them all at once or could you page/delay-load them?

Comment: yes, I do need to create view models for each reading list item. any other way than the above which could be faster in terms of performance?

Comment: `ko.mapping` does quite a lot, so you might be able to make things quicker by manually iterating the list and manually creating your own view model classes.  If you really need *all* those view models immediately (and I would have thought you could get away with just loading a first page initially) then you'll have to go through the list which is likely to be slow.  I would be looking at ways you can do some of the slow parts (iterating the list, creating the view models) *after* page load

Comment: I haven't used it, but this plugin claims to be faster than ko.mapping: http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is an issue then you can use the mappings options to include or exclude the properties of the object that you want mapped, this could help a bit.

```
var mapping = {
    'include': ["propertyToInclude", "alsoIncludeThis"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```